# XMLHttpRequest issue with Windows Standard User

Tags: firefox, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, windows-users

I have an HTML page with the following JS script on it. The script sends the request (in Firefox) when logged in as an Admin User but not as a Standard User:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", "http://localhost:8400");
req.onreadystatechange = pingHandler;
req.send();
```

I have tried disabling the Windows Firewall with no luck. Any ideas what's blocking the request to go out?

Comment: What about `req.send();`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I've changed it.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that Firefox was not configured to allow mixed content (http request from within an https environment) for the Standard User. This change was made only for the Admin User, and it was incorrectly assumed that it was applied to all users.